# JSON value doesn't change inside ajax success callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, asynchronous

I'm working on a django reddit clone project, just to improve my skills. I wanted to implement AJAX to it so the page doesn't refresh when someone upvotes. I made an API with django rest framework, which has upvoted and downvoted boolean values. However, when I try to change the upvoted value to false in my javascript, it doesn't work, but changing it to true when it's false works and updates the template. This is probably confusing so here is some code.

```
class UpvoteAPIToggle(APIView):
def get(self, request, id=None, format=None):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=id)
    all_post_upvotes = post.upvotes.all()
    all_post_downvotes = post.downvotes.all()
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
    upvoted = False
    downvoted = False
    if profile not in all_post_upvotes:
        post.upvotes.add(profile)
        downvoted = False
        if profile in all_post_downvotes:
            post.upvotes.remove(profile)
            upvoted = False
            downvoted = True
    else:
        post.downvotes.remove(profile)
        upvoted = True

    serializer = PostSerializer(all_post_upvotes, many=True, read_only=True)
    serialized_upvotes = serializers.serialize("json", all_post_upvotes)
    upvote_counter = 0
    data = {
        "upvoted":upvoted,
        "downvoted": downvoted,
        "all_post_upvotes":serialized_upvotes,
        "upvote_counter":upvote_counter
    }
    return Response(data)
```

this is the class based rest view.

```
$.ajax({
            url: upvoteUrl,
            data: {},
            dataType: "json",
            success: 
            (data)=>{
                checkVote(data)
            }
        })

        function checkVote(data){
        if (data.upvoted){
            data.upvote_counter--;
            data.upvoted = false
        }else{
            data.upvote_counter++;
            data.upvoted = true
            $(".upvote-btn").css("color","orange");
            $("#upvoteCounter").text(data.upvote_counter)
        }
    }
```

Here is the jquery part from the template. It is called upon upvote button click. I'll say it again just to remind you, when it's not upvoted and you click, it turns to true, vice-versa doesn't work, when it's true it remains true.

Comment: Small thing, unrelated to the issue, but you can just use `success: checkVote` instead of the arrow function

Comment: It was like that before, I just experimenter a bit, but I'm gonna change it back thanks.